# how can I change the collation of a data base?

Tags: sql-server, collation

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Express R2 and in the istallation wizard I selected the Modern_Spabish_CS_AS collation because I want all the databases in the server are case sesitive.

However, when I restore a backup, although in the properties of the server and the database the collation is Modern_CS_AS, when I query the databse is not case sensitive.

When I use this query:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') DBCollation,collation_name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Users]') AND name = 'User'
```

I get this result:

```
DB_COllation: Modern_Spanish_CS_AS
CollationName: Modern_Spanish_CI_AS
```

So although the collation of the DB is CS (case sensitive) it seems that collation is not case sensitive.

What is db collation and what is collation name? In the installation I did not not see the posibility to set de collation name, only the collation, so I don't know what I did wrong.

I would like that the new databases are case sensitive and change the collation at the existing database. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296428/changing-sql-server-collation-to-case-insensitive-from-case-sensitive

Comment: also, read this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/f5cd6d91-0a0e-41be-8801-97d5b7bef98b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it in Database Explorer -> Select any DB -> Properties

[image: DB Properties]

Comment: If I go to the property of the database as you say, I can see that the collation of the database es Modern_Spanish_CS_AS.

Comment: I edit my fisrt post because is in the seleciton when the database has not in count the case sensitive, in the unique constraints it does it.