# Vb.net sqlconnections parameters don't respect lower case or upper case letters

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce, sqlparameter

Why don't the parameters respect lower case or upper case letters? If I put 'Londres' or 'lONDRES' in any parameter then the result is always the same (I used that to login and password).

I did use SQL CE 3.5 with [Case Sensitive} on True, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I vaguely remember SQL Server 2000 accepting passwords in a case-insensitive fashion, but it had nothing to do with connections. What DB are you using?

Comment: Thanks, im using SQL CE 3.5

Comment: The parameters do respect this, but your server doesn`t if the server uses a case-insensitive collation.[Changing SQL Server collation to case insensitive from case sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296428/changing-sql-server-collation-to-case-insensitive-from-case-sensitive/3296444#3296444)

Comment: @Heslacher The link you provide refers to `Sql Server` **not** `Sql Server Compact`

Comment: @RaulSolis Did you set the *Case Sensitive* option during the creation of the database?

Comment: @Chris this is for SqlCe the same.

Comment: @Heslacher No, this not for SQLCE the same. Case sensitive has been introduced in SQLCE 3.5 SP1 See this [link](http://erikej.blogspot.fr/2008/07/working-with-case-sensitive-sql-compact.html) for more informations.  You can't use the T-SQL snippets that your link provides with SQLCE. There is no "Server" in SQLCE...