# How to make Case-In-Sensitive with Linq

Tags: linq

**EDIT:**

Also like to know:
what if; if i have a data that is not upper case? or have mixed of upper or lower case? how you will handle this?

i am trying to query my resultset

```
IQueryable<CategoryObject>  filteredCategories = _catRepo.GetAllEmployees();


 filteredCategories = filteredCategories.Where(c=> c.CategoryName.Contains("Blocks"));
```

However, i don't get any result becuase the CategoryName is For(Upper Case) in the database. I have no idea how to use contains to filter case insensitive string? I want basically if someone type like;

```
filteredCategories = filteredCategories.Where(c=> c.CategoryName.Contains("Blocks"));
```

OR

```
filteredCategories = filteredCategories.Where(c=> c.CategoryName.Contains("blocks"));
```

OR

```
filteredCategories = filteredCategories.Where(c=> c.CategoryName.Contains("blocKS"));
```

The result should be the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
filteredCategories = categoriesList.Where(c=> c.CategoryName.ToUpper().Contains("BLOCKS"));
```

That'll remove any case issues.

Comment: what if; if i have a data that is not upper case? or have mixed of upper or lower case? how you will handle this?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  As long as you change the value in your database to upper case and check against an upper case value it will work.  For example BLocks would become BLOCKS and would still match.  Just check upper vs upper every time.

Comment: You aren't changing the data in the database per se - you are only altering the local value and comparing it against another local value.  It works and is one of probably many solutions.

Comment: @AbuHamzah, this (or alternatively ToLower and comparing to a lower-case string) is indeed the normal way to approach case-insensitivity if there isn't a directly supported method to do so.

Comment: @Brian: I was expecting a better way of doing than `toupper or tolower` but I guess that's the only way to go :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
filteredCategories = categoriesList.Where(c=> c.CategoryName.IndexOf("blocks", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

First way, as said before - use ToUpper():

```
var filterString = "bLoCkS"
filteredCategories = categoriesList.Where(c=> c.CategoryName.ToUpper().Contains(filterString.ToUpper()));
```

Another way - use **Case Insensetive** collation ([Changing SQL Server collation to case insensitive from case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296428/changing-sql-server-collation-to-case-insensitive-from-case-sensitive))  in your database (table, field).