# LINQ to SQL & SQLite - Searching in UTF-8 string

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, utf-8

I am programming an "Articles Archieve" contains articles about law. For this, I am using Linq to SQL and SQLite. And authors' names contain UTF-8 characters. When I search "`oğuz`" term in the search textbox, it returns `KARABULUT, Ayşe/EMİR, Oğuz` - `PİLAT, Oğuz/GÜNAŞTI, Emin` - `AYDOS, Oğuz Sadık` - `İNAL, Oğuz Mehmet`. But it does not find and does not return `OĞUZ, Habip` - `OĞUZOĞLU, Ali`, `OĞUZ, Kemal` - `OĞUZMAN, Cemal`.

In the same way, when I search "`OĞUZ`" term in the search textbox, it returns same datas as "`oğuz`" term.
Here is my code:

```
IQueryable<article> results = (from m in _db.articles
                            where m.author.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower())
                            select m).Distinct();
```

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you try this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107132/case-insensitive-contains-in-linq). currentculture and index of maybe works for you.

```
  List<article> temp= (from m in _db.articles
                       join k in _db.keywordss on m.id equals k.aid                                   
                       select m).Distinct().ToList();

  List<article> result= temp.Where(l => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(m.author.ToLower(), textBox1.Text.ToLower()) >= 0) ).ToList();
```

EDIT: compare options and add this tolower() for case sensivity i hope this work now and check this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143031(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Everything is same. And I don't know why it is. Is it may be due to the SQLite?

Comment: Absolutely. First I set IQueryable type, so it gave me error. But later, I changed the type, it was good.