# Password check-constraint SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraint

I'm trying to create a password constraint that must contain:

-at least 1 Upper case

-at least 1 number

-at least 5 characters long

I have searched a lot and i just can't make it work

for example, i have tried this

```
(len([PASSWORD])>(5) AND [PASSWORD] like '%[0-9]%' AND [PASSWORD] like '%[A-Z]%')
```

now, it will accept it if the password contains a number, but it will also accept it when the password contains no capitals at all, or only capitals, this confuses me, and i've tried many combinations

```
[password] LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

that also didn't work, i have tried many code snippets from stackoverflow and people have marked it as answered, this makes me wonder, is it a problem on my part or am i doing something wrong? i am very confused right now

```
(len([PASSWORD])>(5) AND [PASSWORD] like '%[A-Z]%' AND [PASSWORD] like '%[0-9]%')
```

this *should* not allow the password: "wefwefew123" right? well, it does. it does not accept "wefwefew" though, so it does work with 0-9, what's wrong with the A-Z?

It's probably an dumb mistake and i will probably feel dumb after, but i can't solve it on my own, do keep in mind I'm no pro ;)

Comment: Have you checked if the collation on your table/database is set to case sensitive?

Comment: Storing passwords is usually a really bad plan - it's usually better to store (salted) password hashes - which as a bonus means you don't have to set a maximum password length. The password policy is, then, usually better enforced in the application.

Comment: i followed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296428/changing-sql-server-collation-to-case-insensitive-from-case-sensitive 

and it turned out to be case insensative

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever 

Yes i was planning on hasing it later, i just wanted to make this work first

Comment: Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q), and if you still think storing passwords in your database is a good idea, watch it again.

Comment: @stefan if you are going to hash it later then there is no point in putting this logic on the database side, put it in your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a Case Sensitive Collation to help you out and compare password with a lower case version of it like below using your code:

```
(len([PASSWORD])>(5) AND [PASSWORD] like '%[0-9]%' 
AND [PASSWORD] <> Lower([PASSWORD]) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI)
```

Or my own example would be like this:

```
Declare @Password varchar(20) = 'Hello'
if @Password <> Lower(@Password) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI
    PRINT 'Upper'
else
    PRINT 'lower'
```

Comment: I'm trying to  have a combination of uppercase and number, this code accepts when its only lowercase example: 
Password1 = correct

password1 = incorrect

Password = incorrect

Comment: Apologies I had left in the = from my testing. It was meant to be <> The updated should work now