# Data can not be inserted to the table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a db.php file which connection is established here to the database

```
<?php 
   $host = "localhost"; 
   $user = "root";
    $pass = ""; 
    $db_name = "aigsonlinedb"; 
    $con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db_name);
    function formatDate($date){
    return date('g:i a', strtotime($date));
    }
    ?>
```

"Index.php" file here is a form where the data should be sent and retrieved from the database

```
      <?php 
      include 'db.php';
      ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat System in PHP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all"/>
    <script>
        function ajax(){

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        req.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){

        document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = req.responseText;
        } 
        }
        req.open('GET','chat.php',true); 
        req.send();

        }
        setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);
    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="ajax();">

    <div id="container">
        <div id="chat_box">
        <div id="chat"></div>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter name"/> 
        <textarea name="msg" placeholder="enter message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send it"/>

        </form>
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $msg = $_POST['msg'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO chat (name,msg) VALUES ($name','$msg')";

        $run = $con->query($query);

        if($run){
            echo "<embed loop='false' src='chat.wav' hidden='true'       autoplay='true'/>";
        }
        }
        ?>
   </div>
   </body>
    </html>
```

chat.php where the data is fetched from the database

```
<?php 
    include 'db.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC";
    $run = $con->query($query);
    while($row = $run->fetch_array()) :
        ?>
            <div id="chat_data">
                <span style="color:green;"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></span> :
                <span style="color:brown;"><?php echo $row['msg']; ?></span>
                <span style="float:right;"><?php echo formatDate($row['date']);        ?></span>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile;?>
```

The only problem is the data can not be sent to the database.

Comment: you got error message?

Comment: We cannot say much here, since your code structure is unclear. Please edit your question and show how the two code pieces are linked. Also specify what "is not working" actually means.

Comment: This code is very open to mysql injection--it's the textbook example.  Please use prepared statements.

Comment: use `mysqli_error()` to return the last error description for the most recent function call.

Comment: can you try with `VALUES` instead of values?

Comment: @arkascha if it is clear now, would you please have your comment.

Comment: @Ray Thanks, I will do necessary modifications  before its delivery.

Comment: Sorry, no, it is not clear how the two code snippets work together. I cannot see any `require` or `include` statement or similar.

Comment: @Milan Thanks but it didn't work.

Comment: Also you still did not reply to @noushidp comment above asking of you have any error in your http servers error log file.

Comment: @Milan SQL actually is case insensitive.

Comment: @Ray Prepared statements alone do _not_ prevent sql injection attacks. You have to use "prepared statements" combined with "parameter binding" for that.

Comment: @arkascha yes, but it can be configured as case sensitive

Comment: @Milan That is interesting, didn't know that. How can you "configure" a language?

Comment: @AhmadReshadZazai can you echo `$query`, along with `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: @Milan Sorry, I cannot find any such feature in the MySQL documentation. Are you sure such thing exists? I doubt it...

Comment: @arkascha check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3296444/5801516

Comment: @Milan Sorry, no, not really. That is about string comparison being case insensitive. That has _nothing_ to do with the language parser working case insensitive. Such thing actually would violate the SQL standard.

Comment: @arkascha +1, my bad

Comment: @arkascha fair point, you can have a prepared statement without any bound parameters--it's the act of binding parameters that provides the security from injection.

Comment: @Milan I this is what I got for echo query INSERT INTO chat (name,msg) VALUES ('Milan','Hi') and no output for mysqli_error($con);

Comment: @AhmadReshadZazai can you echo `$run`?

Comment: @Milan I got no output.

Comment: @AhmadReshadZazai it seems that query fails for some reason. can you copy and try this  `$query = "INSERT INTO \`chat\`(\`name\`,\`msg\`) VALUES ('foo','bar')"`.  if it fails again, can you manually execute this query with phpMyAdmin?  how do you check if data is saved to a database?

Answer (score 0):

In the end of String ; vor SQL Statements. And PHP variables in double quotes and extra double quotes in values for define the datatype of sql

Comment: Sorry, but this is all simply wrong. You should try those suggestions yourself.