# Transform an entire database varchar to uppercase

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This week the risk unit told us that our system must only accept texts in uppercase. We are on production for almost 6 months and this wasn't contemplated on the initial project. Is there any easy way to transform all varchars of the database to uppercase?

Comment: [Changing SQL Server collation to case insensitive from case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296428/changing-sql-server-collation-to-case-insensitive-from-case-sensitive#3296444)

Comment: How do you define "easy"?

Comment: No, what I really need is like a css' 'text-transform: uppercase' to the whole database's columns/rows/fields.

Comment: The "easy" would be something that I don't need to do 'UPDATE table SET column = UPPER(column)' for every table and column

Comment: You can't just magically change the case of your data. To update data requires an update statement.

Comment: What is so hard about generating update statements for every table/column which is a varchar?  Write a query that generates your SQL using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` or `sys.columns` then just run it.

Comment: The problem is that it is an ERP, there is about 150 tables, but ok, I will do it on "brutal force". Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best possible approach, but I use it sometimes. It uses [sys.columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) catalog view, generates dynamic statement using [FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) 
 clause and executes generated statement with [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
DECLARE 
    @stm nvarchar(max),
    @err int

SELECT @stm = (
    SELECT CONCAT(
        'UPDATE ', OBJECT_NAME(c.OBJECT_ID), 
        ' SET ',
        c.name,
        ' = UPPER(',
        c.name, '); ')
    FROM sys.columns AS c
    JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
    WHERE t.name = 'varchar'
    ORDER BY c.OBJECT_ID
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stm
IF @err = 0 
    PRINT 'OK'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'Error'
```