# How to make MySql table data Case Sensitive?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, primary-key, collation

I wanted to enter data in MySql table's primary key field with respect to case sensitivity.
But default it is not considering case sensitivity for table data.

Here is my query.

```
mysql> select id from product where id = 'a1';
+----+
| id |
+----+
| A1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into product values('a1', 'SomeName', 'SomeName', 200, 10, 10);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'a1' for key 'product.PRIMARY'
```

[image]

Also i have tried **Collation** while creating table but not getting result as required.
can any one suggest which collation has to use or any other technique to make table's column domain case sensitive.

Comment: Having case-sensitive primary keys is just an awful idea.  Don't do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing SQL Server collation to case insensitive from case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296428/changing-sql-server-collation-to-case-insensitive-from-case-sensitive)

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you please elaborate on the awful idea part? I'm also facing this issue, and I can't find a proper explanation anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE product
    MODIFY COLUMN id VARCHAR(...) COLLATION ..._bin NOT NOT NULL;
```

Where the `...` are the current column size and character set.

The only case-sensitive things I can think of are

- base-64
- Unix file names

But those do not seem likely as PKs.  What is your use case?  Most things are better off being case-insensitive.

(A Comment links to a SQL Server suggestion using `ALTER DATABASE`; that will not work for MySQL since that only changes the *default* for subsequently created tables.)