# Google Cloud SQL Server sqlserver GRANT Connect

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I would like to run SAGE ERP in or google cloud project using Cloud SQL Server. I have run into 2 issues.

1. I need to change the collation to case sensitive
2. The ERP system needs to create multiple SQL users which is not possible since the sqlserver user created by the GCP does not have permission to grant connect permissions. is it possible to increase this users permissions ?

My other option is to use a compute engine and setup SQL server on that, i would prefer to stay with Cloud SQL if it is possible.

any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second point,to create DB users a grant permissions, you can connect to the instance using the SQL Server Management [Studio](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/quickstart#connect-using-ssms) if you have window as OS, if not, you can use the “sqlcmd” tool , in the document “Install sqlcmd and bcp the SQL Server command-line tools on [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu)” or [mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15#macos) you can see the steps to install it. Then you have to follow the instructions of the document “[Install the Cloud SQL Proxy client on your local machine](http://%20https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/quickstart-proxy-test#install-proxy-sqlserver)” to set up the connection to the instance.

Once you are connected to the instance, you can add users to the database using the SQL Server Management Studio console or using this command:

- Creates the login username with password 'password'.
  CREATE LOGIN user_name
  WITH PASSWORD = 'password';
  GO

-- Creates a database user for the login created above.
CREATE USER username FOR LOGIN username;
GO

You can see more detail of the previous script on the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure).

Once you have created the users, you can add one of the Fixed-Database Roles listed in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017#fixed-database-roles).If you are using the command line you can use the following command:

EXE SP_ADDROLEMEMBER ‘role_name’, ‘user_name’

You can see more detail about adding roles in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-adding-a-database-user).

Regarding the first point,  I think that you can use the same way described in the this [response](http://%5Dhttps://stackoverflow.com/a/3296444/8210931)

Comment: Hi, this does not seem to work as the user that is created still does not have high enough privileges. Google does not seem to allow this functionality in its Cloud SQL instances.

Comment: what ERP system are you using? Do you know the users and the permissions that the ERP creates? Could you create them manually?